# iTunes ported for Linux?

Tags: linux, itunes, port

Is there any ported version of iTunes for Linux?

Really would like it; i need to restore my iPod. Emulation is slow because i have here a 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu here is a hint

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/itunes

The best way to do it, would be to install a Virtual Machine of Windows.

Comment: via VirtualBox is probably the best method at the moment, but it feels like "accepting defeat" so to speak ;)

Comment: Accepting defeat ? Well people buy proprietary hardware, and they think they can run it under anything. Buy something more "open" if you want to be platform free.

Comment: They get lucky that they can use it under Windows and not Only Mac OSX.

Comment: I actually have Windows 7 installed on my computer, i am just trying to be independent from it. Windows is crap, Linux is fast, it's the way it is, and i know, it will be for that for a longgg time.

Answer (score 1):

Most iPods can be synced with Amarok: http://amarok.kde.org/wiki/Media_Device:IPod

Comment: While this does work with some devices, it will be quickly become obsolete as the newer devices are encrypted to prevent syncing with 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes will work with [WINE](http://www.winehq.org), but not perfectly without flaws.

Referring to the [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347), iTunes <= 9.0 works good, but 9.0.1 and newer is crap.
Here's a [review about iTunes 7.3 via Wine](http://www.wine-reviews.net/applications/itunes-73-on-linux-with-wine.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore the iPod without iTunes, which unfortunately has no direct port for Linux.

Comment: yeah, but can i restore with it? probably not i guess

Comment: No those applications won't restore it. Edited my answer to reflect. People have attempted to get it working under Wine, but even then only certain features work (playing music and movies). You could however make a Windows VM as Livinloud suggested.

Comment: "no direct port for Linux." Thanks be to Jesus for the small mercies! :D

Comment: lol, I hear ya.

Comment: only yesterday i had a 'run-in' with a teenager, she wrecked daddy's PC throughly with iTunes. needless to say we didn't part as best friends, but daddy was happy and he's the one paying me after all. :D

Comment: how would someone wreck a PC with itunes?  I can imagine filling the hard drive or changing default programs for various extensions, but I cannot imagine doing real damage with itunes, is it pretty harmless....

Comment: for starters it was taking over the properties for all sorts of media files, digging deep into the system resources, mind you this was an older cerlery computer with 512 MB RAM, add to this how easy 'not so computer literate' folks get scared if the computer is acting strangely (like the firewall going berserk asking to allow network acces for a plethora of nonsensical stuff installed with iTunes) and you'll have a recipe for desaster.

Comment: @John T, @Livinloud, i already told this in my question "Emulation is slow because i have here a 1 GB of RAM."(I know you actually call it Virtualization.)

Answer (score 0):

There might be only to way to restore your iPod with iTuns :

1. Run iTunes windows with wine (but it's emulation and I'm not even sure it would work or connect to the iPod)
2. Just like Livinloud said, using windows with a *Virtualization* software like VirtualBox, VMWare Server, etc.

There is no port of iTunes on Linux and will never be, becaus iTunes is a closed software developed by Apple, and they don't really need to care about Linux users (it's a shame.. :/).