# How long will it be before Apple develops iTunes for Linux OS?

Tags: ubuntu, iphone, itunes, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [iTunes alternative for Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/9811/itunes-alternative-for-linux)
>   [iTunes ported for Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/83655/itunes-ported-for-linux)

Hi

How long will it be before Apple develops iTunes for Linux OS? What I need is to do firmware update in Ubuntu, but unfortunately haven't found any ways to do that yet. I know that it is possible to use Virtualbox or wine, but still in the most of the times iTunes doesn't want to work on wine and  for Virtualbox I need to install again that Windows from which I switched into Ubuntu just a few months ago and don't want to go back to it.

What do Linux users who have iPod Touch(iPhone) do in this case?

Any suggestions to solve the problem will be pleased.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update firmware of my iPod Touch in Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/165889/how-to-update-firmware-of-my-ipod-touch-in-ubuntu) - Please don't post duplicate questions if it isn't answered soon enough by your standards. Questions take some time to gain popularity and be answered =) Please be patient. If you have something to add to your question, please use the "edit" option.

Comment: @BloodPhilia. But this is completely another question i think. It is more about iTunes rather than firmware. I mentioned firmware just as an example.

Comment: I agree.  The focus of the question is quite different.

Comment: Actually, a bigger problem with this question is that it is mostly asking "how long" will it take for iTunes to come on Linux. And this is only a matter of guess, since nobody knows that. (This is why three persons voted to close this question as "subjective and argumentative" or "not a real question"). However, if we take away the "speculative" part of the question, it seems more like a duplicate of these questions: [iTunes ported for Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/83655/) and [iTunes alternative for Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/9811/).

Answer (score 4):

Probably never since many versions of iTunes [run under wine](http://www.wine-reviews.net/applications/itunes-73-on-linux-with-wine.html).  You can visit [wineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) to see which version of iTunes work under wine & which do not.  In  a nutshell: avoid the 'bleeding edge' of iTunes as access to the store is about the last thing to get working apparently.

Comment: Also Apple is bushing its own Unix, so as far as I can see, they have nothing to profit by making iTunes compatible with Linux which is dangerously similar to Mac OS X